# How to insert data from a React form to mysql?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to develop my first react application. The backend works properly. Anyway I don't know how to insert the entered data in a react form into my database. I tried with axios, but I had many problems. Here is my code:
Backend:

```
router.post('/insert',(req,res) =>{


    jsondata = req.body;
    description = jsondata['description'];
    distance = jsondata['distance'];
    hours = jsondata['hours'];
    minutes = jsondata['minutes'];
    seconds = jsondata['seconds'];


    conn.query('INSERT INTO run (description, distance, hours, minutes, seconds) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [description,distance,hours,minutes,seconds], (err) =>{
        if(err)
        res.send(err)
        if(!err)
        res.send("Insert succeded.")
        
    })
})
```

Frontend:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
function Insert(){

    return(

        <div>
            <form>
                <p>Insert the details of your run</p>
                <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Insert a description of your run"></input>
                <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Insert a description of your run"></input>
                <input type="number" id="description" placeholder="Insert the distance of your run"></input>
                <input type="number" id="description" placeholder="Insert the hours of your run"></input>
                <input type="number" id="description" placeholder="Insert the minutes of your run"></input>
                <input type="number" id="description" placeholder="Insert the seconds of your run"></input>
                <button id="btn">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    );


}

export default Insert;
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Continue to try with Axios, it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on inputs you need to put methods to handle their change, you can store values in useState, example:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

...

<input type="text" value={name} onChange={setName} />
```

then, handle submit form by adding method call like this

```
<form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
```

where you would gather your input data and sent it with axios, example:

```
 handleOnSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const data = {
          name: name
          // other fields...

        }

        axios.post('http://your-url.com', data)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
```